# Entity Framework multiple counts with a single query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Sorry if this has been asked, but how can I improve the following with a single call to the database?

```
var statsModel = new
{
     Total = _db.Messages.Count(),
     Approved = _db.Messages.Count(x => x.Approved),
     Rejected = _db.Messages.Count(x => !x.Approved),
};
```

Comment: at least `Rejected = Total - Approved`

Comment: I mean I could easily return all Messages and filter down form there, but I might have thousands of messages. Returning the entire table would be an intense query, and thats why I just need to return the count.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you can compute the `Rejected` by Total and Accepted like this:

```
Rejected = Total - Approved
```

And for further improvement you can compute both of them in one shot;

```
from m in _db.Messages
let Total =  _db.Messages.Count()
let Accept = _db.Messages.Count(x => x.Approved == true)
select new {Total , Accept})
```

**UPDATE:**
a simple hack for now : just take the first row

```
(from m in _db.Messages
let Total =  _db.Messages.Count()
let Accept = _db.Messages.Count(x => x.Approved == true)
select new {Total , Accept}).Take(1);
```

But I'm looking for a cleaner one

Comment: Last question related to this. It is working correctly, but returning the {Total,Accept} for each message. So what I did was "from m in _db.Messages
let Total =  _db.Messages.Count()
let Accept = _db.Messages.Count(x => x.Approved == true)
select new {Total , Accept}).FirstOrDefaul();

Answer (score 13):

This might help:

```
var statsModel =(
        from message in _db.Messages
        group message by 1 into g
        select new
        {
            Total = g.Count(),
            Approved =g.Count (x =>x.Approved),
            Rejected =g.Count (x =>!x.Approved)
        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

In C# (rather than LINQ query), async syntax:

```
var statsModel = await _db.Messages
.GroupBy(m => 1, (g, mm) => new
{
    Total = mm.Count(),
    Approved = mm.Count(m => m.Approved),
    Rejected = mm.Count(m => !m.Approved)
})
.SingleAsync();
```

Comment: It fails if table is empty, so SingleOrDefault and an additonal if is needed.

Comment: @kemsky That depends on whether an empty table is Exceptional in your Application.