# Get the next and previous sql row by Id and Name, EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Assume we have the following data in a SQL Server table (sorted by name) :

```
Id   Name        LName
-------------------------
5   Abbas        Dayyan
3   Mohammad     KD
4   Nima         Ahmad
1   Omid         Zangene
2   Pedram       Ahmadi
```

we have an Id query string and we wanna get the next and previous row (if exists) from Id.

e.g :

the Id query string is 4, so we wanna get **Mohammad KD** as previous row and **Omid Zangene** as next row.

Could you please guide me how can do it with LINQ to Entity Framework.

**Edit:**
In practice the number of table rows is around 1 million.
Table rows didn't sort by Name by default, wa need to sort them by Name for the result.

Comment: Is this list ordered by Name always?

Comment: @Dharun : No, we wanna to sort it by Name for the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
var result = (from person in db.People
              where person.Id == id
              let ordered = db.People.OrderBy(p => p.Name)                  
              let reversed = db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.Name)                  
              let previous = reversed.SkipWhile(p => p.Id != id).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
              let next = ordered.SkipWhile(p => p.Id != id).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
              select new { previous, next }).First();
```

**Edit:** Took the new specifications into account.

**Edit 2:** Modified the code to not use `LastOrDefault`, which doesn't work with LINQ to Entities.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I get the error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method LastOrDefault method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @atticae: I revised the solution.  Does the revised code work?

Comment: Haven't tested your specific solution, but yeah that's about the same I ended up with.

Comment: On a second thought. I am pretty sure EF can't work with SkipWhile either. I translated that into something more basic.

Comment: @atticae: Good work!  If you post your code as an answer, I will delete my answer and vote yours up.

Comment: I'll see if I can find the code tomorrow. I'm probably just going to edit it into your answer though. After all you got me started on the right track.

Comment: for large records, this could be a performance overkill. Why not remove `let reversed` altogether and just do `let previous = db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.Name).SkipWhile(p => p.Id != id).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` which will result in single call to DB and won't load all DB records as in `reversed[]`. Same for `ordered` and `next` of course

Comment: @Korayem: I believe it's all one database call. Writing it your way might make the one database call more efficient, but I'm not sure. With LINQ to objects at least, the performance would be about the same because `reversed` would be lazily evaluated and would only enumerate the items until `previous` is found and wouldn't store anything. The bigger issue is that `SkipWhile()` does not work with LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @RiskyMartin I know each `db.<entities>.Whatever()` (i.e. `db.People.OrderBy(p => p.Name)`) will always result in a new DB connection.

Comment: @Korayem: That does not appear to be the case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8894781/480799).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 int id = 4;     
 var list = (from x in ctx.Table
            where x.id >= id - 1 && x.id <= id + 1
            select x).OrderBy(o -> o.name).ToList();
```

edit: this will return elements with ID 3,4 and 5. I dont know if you are actually ordering the table in the database by name, but if you are i think it would be easier to just use a loop instead of using linq to get the previous and next element.

update: sorted the result by name

Comment: *i think it would be easier to just use a loop instead of using linq to get the previous and next element* - not if the table has millions or billions of records.

Comment: this is not correct as it requires ID's to be asc/desc.