# What is a good way in terms of performance to check duplicate entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to check for duplicate entries before saving entity to the database. Below is my current code

```
if (db.Product.Any(x => x.Code == entity.Code))
{
  error.Add('Duplicate code');
}

if (db.Product.Any(x => x.Name == entity.Name))
{
  error.Add('Duplicate name');
}

if (db.Product.Any(x => x.OtherField == entity.OtherField))
{
  error.Add('Duplicate other field');
}
```

The problem with code above is that it made 3 db call to validate entity. This table has millions of record and this app will be used by thousand users. So it will hurt the performance badly. I could make it one query though

```
if (db.Product.Any(x => x.Code == entity.Code || x.Name == entity.Name || x.OtherField == entity.OtherField))
{
  error.Add('Duplication found');
}
```

The problem with the second code is that i wouldnt know which field is duplicate.

What is the better way of doing this? Should i depend only on unique constraint in the database? However error from the database is ugly.

**EDIT**

I need to show all errors to the user if more than 1 duplicate fields. 
Consider the scenario: if the duplicate fields are code and name. If i tell the user that the code already exists, then he changes the code and try to save it again. Then the second error (name field) shows. It makes the user hit save for a couple of times before successfully saving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have indexes on the fields `Name`, `Code`, and `OtherField`, then duplicate checking will not too long, but will still be 3 calls to the database instead of 1.

The usual solution in this case is the counting of duplicates. Then if count is equals to 0, there isn't duplicates.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894684/entity-framework-multiple-counts-with-a-single-query) you'll find some hacks to do it.

Short example:

```
var counts =(
    from product in db.Products
    group product by 1 into p
    select new
    {
        Name = p.Count(x => x.Name == name),
        Code = p.Count(x => x.Code == code),
        OtherField = p.Count(x => x.OtherField == otherFields)
    }
).FirstOrDefault();

if (counts.Name > 0)
    error.Add("Duplicate name");

if (counts.Code > 0)
    error.Add("Duplicate code");
```

Update: it's seems that it's possible to solve the problem even more simple method:

```
var duplicates =(
    from product in db.Products
    group product by 1 into p
    select new
    {
        Name = p.Any(x => x.Name == name),
        Code = p.Any(x => x.Code == code),
        OtherField = p.Any(x => x.OtherField == otherFields)
    }
).FirstOrDefault();

if (duplicates.Name)
    error.Add("Duplicate name");
```

Comment: I really like this approach. But what do you think the performance? Wouldnt count scan all records in the table?

Comment: Most db engines are optimized for counts, but `Any` is usually better because it stops at the first record found.

Comment: @Reynaldi You need indexes in `Products` table for fields `Name`, `Code`, and `OtherField`, then SQL could count rows in O(log N) time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    string duplicateField;

    bool validationResult = db.Product.Any(x => {
            if(x.Code == entity.Code){
            duplicateField = "Code";
                return true;
            }
    // Other field checks here

}

if(validationResult){
// Error in field <duplicateField>
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong then code blocks won't work with enitity framework.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can select duplicate entity

```
var product = db.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == entity.Code
                                               || x.Name == entity.Name
                                               || x.OtherField == entity.OtherField);

if (product == null)
;//no duplicates

if (product.Code == entity.Code)
{
  error.Add('Duplicate code');
}

if (product.Name == entity.Name)
{
  error.Add('Duplicate name');
}

if (product.OtherField == entity.OtherField)
{
  error.Add('Duplicate other field');
}
```

2- You can create stored procedure for insert and check for duplicates in it;

EDIT:
OK, you can write something like this

```
    var duplicates = (from o in db.Products
              select new
              {
                  codeCount = db.Products.Where(c => c.Code == entity.Code).Count(),
                  nameCount = db.Products.Where(c => c.Name == entity.Name).Count(),
                  otherFieldCount = db.Products.Where(c => c.OtherField == entity.OtherField).Count()
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will select number of each duplicate by fields.
One thing to note: you should have unique constraints in database anyway, because while u validating and saving data, another row with these values may be inserted before u insert them.

Comment: IF thousands of code are there then what will you do ?

Comment: @Giorgi I've tried #1 also. However it only shows 1 error (either code/name/otherfield) even if more than 1 fields are duplicate. The stored procedure approach seems the better option i guess.