# Why EF core can not translate the count?

Tags: ef-core-3.0

I want to query multiple aggregate values from the database with the fastest in EF core way, I have found this [Entity Framework multiple counts with a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894684/entity-framework-multiple-counts-with-a-single-query) and tried this

```
        public Task<VouchersUsageMetrics> BuildVouchersUsageMetrics(
            IQueryable<Voucher> vouchers,
            VoucherSetting voucherSetting,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var startOfToday = this.dateTimeProvider.GetStartOfDay(this.dateTimeProvider.Now);
            return vouchers
                .Select(it => SelectExpressions.GetVoucherStatus.Invoke(it, startOfToday))
                .GroupBy(
                    it => 1,
                    (groupId, groupItems) =>
                        new VouchersUsageMetrics(
                            voucherSetting.TotalPrepaidCount,
                            voucherSetting.MaxAvailablePostpaidCount)
                        {
                            Expired = groupItems.Count(it => it == (long)VoucherStatusEnum.Expired),
                            Assigned = groupItems.Count(it => it == (long)VoucherStatusEnum.Assigned),
                            Requested = groupItems.Count(it => it == (long)VoucherStatusEnum.Requested),
                        })
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

However I am getting next error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (1), 
>   ElementSelector:(ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember) )
>       .Count(it => (long)it == 21)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated...

I have tried

1. to replace `SelectExpressions` with constant.
2. Have tried to remove first `Select`
3. have tried to query the table instead of queryable, e.g. `this.context.Vouchers`

, but always have the same error. I have no idea, why :) Afraid if fail to make it is working, have to use SQL Virtual Views, but really don't like to support them. Or possibly will try dapper for this place.

PS. This how the queryable passed to the method is being built

```
            this.context.Vouchers
                .AsNoTracking()
                .AsExpandableEFCore()
                .Where(it => it.AgencyID == 1);
```

PPS. EF Core 3.1.1 is used

Comment: Start by replacing all unsupported `Count(condition)` with supported `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: I only have experience with EF5 and not EF.NET core: I think both your `GroupBy` methods might be causing the issue, SQL SERVER database may not be able to instantiate the  `VoucherUsageMetrics` type, `As Expandable` may work though. You can create IQueryable extensions which can return `Expression<IQueryable<T>>` if you like to refactor the methods. Try adding `ToList()` before the select method to see if SQL SERVER cannot interpret the following expression

Comment: @IvanStoev works, thank you :)